# Oracle how to de-concatenate a number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have concatenated a number before I run a procedure as I need the procedure to work with a 0 in front of the numbers.

So to concatenate I do

```
update code_temp
set code=0 || code
```

I then will need to undo this after the procedure is run, is there an easy way to remove the 0 at the start of the code?

Thanks.

Comment: How about concatenating the value in procedure itself?

Comment: what is the Data type of `code` I assume it's a varchar2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a substring to ignore the first character:

```
UPDATE code_temp
SET code = substr(code, 2)
```